# How can I loop my WMPLib background music?

Tags: c#

How can I loop my background music, if the song is over?

```
WindowsMediaPlayer musicPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
musicPlayer.URL = "themeSong.mp3";
musicPlayer.controls.play();
```

Comment: There's an event 'MediaPlayer.MediaEnded ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaended?view=windowsdesktop-6.0. If the event occurs => 'Play it again, Sam'

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't find it anywhere.